# Unable to get the reference back from struct array

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following structure from a library:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char pin;              //!< Module pin.
    unsigned char function;         //!< Module function.
} gpio_map_t[];
```

now, in my code I create an instance of the structure like that:

```
gpio_map_t display_spi_pins = {
        {1,1},
        {2,2},
        {3,3},
        {4,4}
    };
```

and then i create a pointer like that:

```
gpio_map_t* spi_pins_pointer = &display_spi_pins;
```

until here everythings goes well, no compilation error.

I would like to know how I get back the reference to display_spi_pins.
I try like that:

```
gpio_map_t display_spi_pins_new_reference = *spi_pins_pointer;
```

but I get a compilation error saying:

> array initializer must be an initializer list

**Edit:**
Dont forget that typedef sctruct... is comming from a library, I can not modify it.

Comment: being C you can use the flexibility of being able to cast almost anything to something else. So in your case you could create another struct/typedef but with same memory layour and where you leave out the []. Then you could cast your existing array to it. That will be a workaround. It is not a good practice to embedd a [] in a typedef as you see, it makes it less flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't declare the type alias `gpio_map_t` as an array type. Instead when need an array of the structure, then declare the *variable* as an array, and use pointers only for references.

Comment: the struct is comming from a library, I can not modify it

Comment: @ojota Then you have no choice, you can't use plain non-pointer `gpio_map_t` other than to create a compile-time array.

Comment: Why? if i can get the pointer to the structure, why i can not get back the reference

Comment: @ojota Pointers and arrays are similar, and an array can be used as a pointer (and a  pointer can be indexed like an array) but arrays have some extra data during compilation that a pointer do not have, like for example the size. The pointer doesn't have that extra data, so the compiler can't create a new array from the pointer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I see what you mean. In fact I have the function with this prototype: function(gpio_map_t gpiomap); and I only have my pointer gpio_map_t *spi_pins_pointer what can i give to the function so that the compiler is happy?. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @ojota, simply use *function(display_spi_pins);* - I bet it's gonna work, you do not even need pointers or references in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access data via pointer in this case you can access to it directly with your array 
`display_spi_pins`

```
for(i=0; i<sizeof(display_spi_pins)/sizeof(display_spi_pins[0]); i++) {
    printf("pin[%d]=%X, function[%d]=%X\n",
           i, display_spi_pins[i].pin,
           i, display_spi_pins[i].function);
}
```

Comment: The error I get it in the last line. If i do it like you say, I get an additional error: array has incomplete element type 'gpio_map_t'

Comment: As I said to Joachim, I can not modify the struct, it is inside the library

Comment: @ojota In that case you can access directelly with your `display_spi_pins` array. Answer updated

Comment: the problem is I have no more access to my array where I need it, I have only my pointer :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're defining `gpio_map_t` as an array of structs whose length is undefined. Do something like that instead :

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char pin;              //!< Module pin.
    unsigned char function;         //!< Module function.
} gpio_map_t;

gpio_map_t[] display_spi_pins = {
    {1,1},
    {2,2},
    {3,3},
    {4,4}
};

gpio_map_t** spi_pins_pointer = &display_spi_pins;
gpio_map_t* display_spi_pins_new_reference = *spi_pins_pointer;
```

(Remember that a `gpio_map_t*` is quite close to a `gpio_map_t[]`).

Comment: please take into account that the structure is comming from the library, and actually it works well, and there is no problem with the initialization, only when getting back the reference

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char pin;              //!< Module pin.
    unsigned char function;         //!< Module function.
} gpio_map_t[]; 


void main()
{
    gpio_map_t display_spi_pins = {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {5,6}};
    gpio_map_t* spi_pins_pointer = &display_spi_pins;
    gpio_map_t* display_spi_pins_new_reference = spi_pins_pointer;

    int i;    

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d: %d  %d\n",i,(display_spi_pins+i)->pin,(display_spi_pins+i)->function);

        if(((display_spi_pins+i)->pin != (*spi_pins_pointer+i)->pin) ||
            ((display_spi_pins+i)->pin != (*display_spi_pins_new_reference+i)->pin) ||
            ((display_spi_pins+i)->function != (*spi_pins_pointer+i)->function) ||
            ((display_spi_pins+i)->function != (*display_spi_pins_new_reference+i)->function))  
            printf("Reference ERROR\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You simply dublicated spi_pins_pointer as display_spi_pins_new_reference. The point is to get original structure back, not just a pointer.